# Third ELIF statement doesn't execute when conditions are met. Executes after I re run code. Python

Tags: python, list, config

I have a bug I cannot explain. I am reading from a config file to see if a directory exists. If it doesn't the script is supposed to make the directory then write that directory to the config file. So I wrote the code:

```
def process_dirconfig_file(config_file_from_sysarg):
config = ConfigParser()
#print(type(config_file_from_sysarg))
config.read(config_file_from_sysarg)
dirconfig_file_Pobj = Path(config_file_from_sysarg)
try:
    if Path.is_file(dirconfig_file_Pobj):
        parseddict = {}
        configsects_set = set()
        for sect in config.sections():
            configsects_set.add(sect)
            for k, v in config.items(sect):
                # print('{} = {}'.format(k, v))
                parseddict[k] = v
        #print(parseddict)
        try:
            if ("base_dir" not in parseddict) or (parseddict["base_dir"] == ""):
                raise Exception(f"Error: Your config file is missing 'base directory' for file processing. Please edit config file to include base directory where csv are stored")
            elif("archive_dir" not in parseddict) or (parseddict["archive_dir"] == ""):
                base_dir = parseddict["base_dir"] #testconfig base = C:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\odfshistory
                Path(base_dir+r"\archive").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                newarchive_dir = base_dir+r"\archive"
                #print(newarchive_dir)
                if "archive" not in configsects_set:
                    config_update = ConfigParser()
                    config_update.add_section("archive")
                    if "archive_dir" not in parseddict:
                        config_update.set("archive","archive_dir",newarchive_dir)
                    with open(config_file_from_sysarg, 'a') as f:
                        f.write('\n' * 2)
                        f.write("#archived csv folder path")
                        f.write('\n')
                        config_update.write(f)
                        parseddict["archive_dir"] = newarchive_dir
                #print(f"Error: Your config file is missing 'archive directory' for file processing")
            elif ("empty_dir" not in parseddict) or (parseddict["empty_dir"] == ""):
                base_dir = parseddict["base_dir"]  # testconfig base = C:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\odfshistory
                Path(base_dir + r"\empty").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                newempty_dir = base_dir + r"\empty"
                if "empty" not in configsects_set:
                    config_update = ConfigParser()
                    config_update.add_section("empty")
                    if "empty_dir" not in parseddict:
                        config_update.set("empty", "empty_dir", newempty_dir)
                    with open(config_file_from_sysarg, 'a') as f:
                        f.write('\n' * 2)
                        f.write("#empty csv folder path")
                        f.write('\n')
                        config_update.write(f)
                        parseddict["empty_dir"] = newempty_dir
            elif ("error_dir" not in parseddict) or (parseddict["error_dir"] == ""):
                base_dir = parseddict["base_dir"]  # testconfig base = C:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\odfshistory
                Path(base_dir + r"\error").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                newerror_dir = base_dir + r"\error"
                if "error" not in configsects_set:
                    config_update = ConfigParser()
                    config_update.add_section("error")
                    if "error_dir" not in parseddict:
                        config_update.set("error", "error_dir", newerror_dir)
                    with open(config_file_from_sysarg, 'a') as f:
                        f.write('\n' * 2)
                        f.write("#error csv folder path")
                        f.write('\n')
                        config_update.write(f)
                        parseddict["error_dir"] = newerror_dir
                #print(f"Error: Your config file is missing 'error directory' for file processing")

        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(e)
        return parseddict
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error: No directory config file. Please create a config file of directories to be used in processing")
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(e)
```

**My issue is that the third ELIF doesn't execute when the config file is empty. It will create the first two directories but not the last directory in the ELIF statement until I re-run the code. Why is this?**

Comment: Only one branch of an `if...elif...else` can be executed. If what you want is for multiple conditions to be met, make each of them separate `if` blocks

Comment: @Randy I have never heard of this rule before. Is there documentation on this? I always assumed if else if works this way. if a, run a.else if b run b, else if c run c. So that if a and b and c are all true, it'd run all of them

Comment: @edo101: your understanding of if/else is incorrect. If you have a group if if/elif/else statements, only one block will ever run. As for documentation, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement

Comment: If if/else blocks worked like you think they do, then imagine this disaster: `if Document.isSensitive: for_the_love_of_God_do_not_delete(); else: byebye_document()`

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou lol thanks that definitely helped.

Comment: @BryanOakley Wow, yeah thanks. still learning as a programming newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Elif` only happens when all other `if` statements have failed, so IF this doesn't happen then `ELSE IF`.

What you need is to replace the `ELIF` with `IF`, then the condition will be checked regardless of the other IF statements

Comment: Got it. I noticed when I nested those 3 if statements under the first if statement, it didn't work either. I had to put all 3 if statements in the same scope as the top if statement, why is this?

Comment: Since you said the first ELIF statement worked (second IF statement), I think the first If statement didn't run, meaning the other IF statements didn't run either, if that makes sense

Comment: Would you also mind setting the question as answered as well please

Comment: Let me clarify, following your suggestino, I did this:
if
   if
   if
   if
I changed what were the 3 elif statements to just if and nested them under my first if statement. However the code skips the nested if statements now. Why is this?

Comment: Because the first iF didn't run, don't nest the other IFs inside the first one, use the same indentation for each IF (the first IF doesn't run, so the ones nested are never checked for)